# Do not add comm if attribute is null

Tags: xslt

I have this string of code that will come delineate all attribute of a feature name.  How ever if the feature is null it will still add a comma.  How do I get the code to ignore any feature name that does not have a value.

```
<xsl:for-each select="Feature">
  <!-- Output the feature name (there may be more than 1 feature associated -->
  <!-- with the point) so this will identify which feature the attrinbutes  -->
  <!-- are associated with.                                                 -->
  <xsl:text>,</xsl:text> <!-- Comma to separate feature name from code or previous feature -->
  <xsl:variable name="FeatName" select="@Name"/> <!-- Feature name -->
  <xsl:for-each select="Attribute">
    <xsl:if test="position() &gt;  0">
      <xsl:text>,</xsl:text> <!-- Include a comma if not first attribute -->
    </xsl:if> <!-- Prefix each attribute name with the feature it belongs to followed by a ':' -->
    <xsl:if test="$includeFieldNames = 'Yes'">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat($FeatName, ':')"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
      <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="Value"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Could you post sample XML input?

Answer (score 1):

> How do I get the code to ignore any feature name that does not have a
>   value.

By processing only features with values:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Feature[Value]">
    <!-- do your processing here -->
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Good, but change `Feature[Value]` to `Feature[Attribute]` ?

Comment: Thanks for the help however that did not work.  Probably need to see the rest of the code and to large to post. I assumed that was the part of the code that was giving me issues.